# mutate per group by in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

i want to identify pieces from sensor data and give them an ID. Therefore I want to group the following dataset by Sensor column and look whether the Value row switched from 0 to 1. When it does the first piece is identified and the caseid switches to 1 (as in the handmade column caseid). It remains 1 as long the value stays 1. When it becomes 0 it should switche back to 0. 
At the next switch from 0 to 1 the caseid should become 2 because the second piece is recognized by the sensor and so forth..

```
time = c("07:00:01","07:00:01","07:00:01","07:00:02","07:00:02","07:00:02","07:00:03","07:00:03","07:00:03","07:00:04",
     "07:00:04","07:00:04","07:00:05","07:00:05","07:00:05","07:00:06","07:00:06","07:00:06","07:00:07","07:00:07",
     "07:00:07","07:00:08","07:00:08","07:00:08","07:00:09","07:00:09","07:00:09")
sensor = c(10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003,
       10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003)
values = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1)
caseid = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,2,0,1)

data = data.frame(time,sensor,values,caseid)
```

(So the data$caseid is what I am trying to get)

I think this can be achieved somehow by a group by but I couldn't get it right so I choose another (sloppy) approach. Thats what i got.

```
data%>% 
filter(Sensor=="10002") -> sensor_data_temp

sensor_data_temp$CaseID2 <- NA 
case_id = 1

for(i in 1:nrow(sensor_data_temp)){

   current_value <- sensor_data_temp[i,"values"]
   next_value <- sensor_data_temp[i+1,"values"]

   if(i+1 > nrow(sensor_data_temp)){
     break
   }

   if(current_value==0 & next_value==1 || current_value==1 & next_value==1){
     sensor_data_temp$CaseID2[i+1] <- case_id
   }
   else if(current_value==1 & next_value==0){
     sensor_data_temp$CaseID2[i+1] <- 0
     case_id = case_id +1
   }
   else{
     sensor_data_temp$CaseID2[i+1] <- 0
   }

}
```

I think thats how I could get the caseid's for one sensor. But I have no idea how I can manage to get every sensor into one dataframe (as the one above)

I am sure there is a much more elegant way to get what I want.

I hope somebody can help me.. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I think you need `lead` from dplyr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(group_by(arrange(data, sensor, time), sensor),
       caseID = case_when(values != 0 ~ cumsum(diff(c(0, values)) > 0),
                          TRUE ~ 0L))
```

Comment: Perfect! Hard to imagine its that easy ^^ as I understand case_when works vectorized but I dont quite understand how it works. Because cumsum(diff(c(0, values)) > 0) gives me a vector. But how does it match this vector to one single column entry? Thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: @JonasPirner `case_when` is pretty well documented; `?case_when` explains it better than I can.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `data.table`

```
library("data.table")

data <- data.table(
  time = c("07:00:01","07:00:01","07:00:01","07:00:02","07:00:02","07:00:02","07:00:03","07:00:03","07:00:03","07:00:04",
         "07:00:04","07:00:04","07:00:05","07:00:05","07:00:05","07:00:06","07:00:06","07:00:06","07:00:07","07:00:07",
         "07:00:07","07:00:08","07:00:08","07:00:08","07:00:09","07:00:09","07:00:09"),
  sensor = c(10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003,
           10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003),
  values = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1),
  caseid = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,2,0,1))

data[, caseID:=ifelse(values==0, 0, cumsum(diff(c(0, values))==1)), sensor][]
```

and without `ifelse()`:

```
data[, caseID:= { v <- rep(0, .N); v[values==1] <- cumsum(diff(c(0, values))==1)[values==1]; v }, sensor][]
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you! I definitely have to check out data.table! I just worked with tidyverse yet ^^